# Bootstrap modal is not displaying

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap modal. 
In view,

```
<div id="basic" class="well modal fade" style="max-width:44em;">
  <div class="model-header">Send Push</div>
  <div class="model-body">
    <div class="top">
      <p>You are sending text push notifications to all devices.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="left" style="width: 100%;height: 100px;float: left;">
      <table style="margin-top: 10px;width: 100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Device Type</th>
          <th>Device Count</th>
          <th>Remaining</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row1">
          <td>IOS</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row2">
          <td>Android</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="right" style="width: 100%;height: 250px;float: left;">
      <div style="width: 100%;height: 55px;margin-top: 25%" id="spinner">

      </div>
      <div id="spinner1" style="width: 100%;text-align: center">Please be patient.This may take awhile</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script for showing modal,

```
     $('#notificationform').ajaxForm({
                            beforeSubmit: validate,
                            beforeSend: function () {
                                $('#spinner1').html('Initializing');
                                $('.modal-header').html('Initializing');
                                $('.top,.left').hide();

                                   $('#basic').popup('show');
                                showLoader();
                            },
                            complete: function (xhr) {
                                var response = xhr.responseText;
                                var status = xhr.status;
                                if (status == '200') {
                                    var res = response.split("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                                    var obj = $.parseJSON(res[0]);
```

Out side this ajaxform function the modal is showing, But i want to show modal in beforesend function.
But this code is not working.I want to show pop up, but it is not displaying anything. Please help me. How to solve this.

Comment: Can you check in console if there is any error

Comment: Have you included `bootstrap.js` ?

Comment: Make a fiddle to demonstrate

Comment: Also check the spellings of the modal classes you have used model-header, model-body etc

Comment: for me the modal is coming  on the screen. I simply copy pasted your code along with bootstrap libraries

Comment: its working fine just add the required libraries                                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: You miswrote the class names `model-header` should be `modal-header`. Same for `model-body`.

Comment: i am trying these all.no modal is not coming

Answer (score 0):

Use Proper Library and latest library for modal...

See the snippest..

```js
$("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#basic").modal('show');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<div id="basic" class="well modal fade" style="max-width:44em;">
            <div class="model-header">Send Push</div>
            <div class="model-body">
                <div class="top">
                    <p>You are sending text push notifications to all devices. </p>
                </div>
                <div class="left" style="width: 100%;height: 100px;float: left;">
                    <table style="margin-top: 10px;width: 100%">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Device Type</th>
                            <th>Device Count</th>
                            <th>Remaining</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row1">
                            <td>IOS</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>0</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row2">
                            <td>Android</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>0</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="right" style="width: 100%;height: 250px;float: left;">
                    <div style="width: 100%;height: 55px;margin-top: 25%" id="spinner">

                    </div>
                    <div id="spinner1" style="width: 100%;text-align: center">Please be patient.This may take awhile</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```